# wicked_pdf is not loading on page javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I am generating a PDF but javascript is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function() {
    // Loading Fonts all the Text Decorations
    Utils.loadSummaryFonts();

    // Load Colors on all uniforms styles
    Colors.loadColorsOnSvgsOnSummary();
  });
</script>
```

Above function is used to generate fonts and is on the template.

```
  @output =  Base64.encode64(@out.html_safe)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
      pdf = render_to_string  pdf:      'artproof',
                            template: '/uniforms/artproof.html.erb',
                            show_as_html: false,
                            javascript_delay: 5000,
                            viewport_size: '1244x1480',
                            orientation: 'Landscape',
                            page_height: '10in'

      send_data(pdf, filename: "artproof-#{@uniform.id}.pdf", type: :pdf)
```

This is how I am generating a PDF.

The javascript function works on html format but not when rendering PDF. What can be the issue?

I tried inserting jquery CDNs but no luck.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: any errors? ....

Comment: @Nezir The question is where I could look for errors. I've got the same issue, the JS is supposed to generate a pie chart, and it simply won't execute.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to add javascript tag in layout pdf file? like this below. The important thing is you must restart the `rails server`

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js" %>
```

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#cdn-reference